# Methane under pressure

Tags: pressure, temperature, ideal-gas, gas

A tank is filled with liquid methane.  Then it is closed. It sits in an infinite room at STP (standard temperature and pressure). (Initial temperature is not important; assume density of liquid methane is 0.5Kg/L.) The tank rises to room temperature.  After reaching standard temperature (20 C), what is the final pressure within the tank?  What is the state (liquid, gas, etc.) of the methane within the tank?

This is not a homework question.  I am just trying to figure this out.

Comment: This reads and can be dealt with like a homework-question so it does fall under the homework-policy. Independent from this, the question has a number of flaws, e.g. what is the original temperature? If you have this, it seems you are only searching for the right tables, hence this is not about physics, but about finding the right tables to apply.

Comment: A search reveals http://www.nist.gov/data/PDFfiles/jpcrd362.pdf - the relevant equation should be the first one in table 7. Maybe that's already enough?

Comment: One could assume the initial temperature was -180 C.  But that makes little difference.  The question is what happens when the liquid methane reaches 20 C.

Answer (score 1):

On the [phase diagram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=methane) of methane, you can see that at RT (20°C), methane can only be gas (or super-critical if pressure is enough). The pressure can be calculated with the ideal gas equation

$\frac{pV}{T}=nR$

You need to calculate quantity of n (in moles, given the volume, density of liquid methane, and the weight of the molecule). [R is a constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_constant), V is given, T is known, so you will get the pressure p.

Comment: I don't think the ideal gas equation would work, as your phase diagram shows it would be in the supercritical region.  But the diagram also shows it is about 10^4 ATM pressure.  That's 150,000 psi.  Yikes!

Comment: Then you can use the [van-der-waals correction](http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/genchem/topicreview/bp/ch4/deviation5.html).

Comment: The ideal equation produces 750 atm. (wrong).  Using Van-der-Waals correction would produce a lower result, which would be even more inaccurate.

Comment: Why do you ask if you already know the solution?

Comment: I don't.  I just have a vague notion (from charts) that don't really make any practical sense. 150,000 psi seems very high to me.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, the volume of a substance as a gas is about a factor 1000 larger compared to the same amount in its liquid state (compare their densities). Then 750 atm or a little bit less don't seem to be so wrong. Close to the super-critical phase, you'll probably have to check for some specific models or experimental results.

Comment: A one liter tank contains 500 grams.  At STP, methane is .716 grams per liter, so at 20C, at 1 ATM, 500 grams would occupy 698 Liters.  So this would mean (ideally) the tank would be at 698 Atmospheres.